# How to make changes to a schema using an LDIF file

Tags: ldap, ldif

I'm using a ruby gem named Ladle (https://github.com/NUBIC/ladle). It spins up an LDAP server and takes in an LDIF file. It also allows you to load a custom schema by passing said schema when creating the server object.

The gem utilizes apacheds 2.0 and by default doesn't support NIS schema. I found that I can enable this by doing the following:

1. In IRB start the LDAP server locally using the Ladle gem
2. Using Apache Directory Studio, connect to the local LDAP server and edit the following: ou=schema -> cn=nis -> m-disabled = FALSE (originally set to TRUE)
3. The following appears in the Ladle log:
   irb(main):156:0> ApacheDS: INFO: Loading nis enabled schema:
   ApacheDS:   Schema Name: nis
   ApacheDS:       Disabled: false
   ApacheDS:       Owner: uid=admin,ou=system
   ApacheDS:       Dependencies: [system, cosine, core]
   ApacheDS: INFO: Loading nis enabled schema:
   ApacheDS:   Schema Name: nis
   ApacheDS:       Disabled: false
   ApacheDS:       Owner: uid=admin,ou=system
   ApacheDS:       Dependencies: [system, cosine, core]
4. At this point, it looks to be working correctly

I need to be able to modify the schema via an LDIF file which I can pass to Ladle, however, I've not been able to do this successfully.

Thanks,
Gennaro